# mortice lock that can be opened by turning the doorhandle either way?

Tags: lock, doorknob

We have a number of doors between rooms on which my partner would like to have traditional porcelain knobs instead of modern handles. Replacing the handles is not an issue, but these doors have (basic) mortice locking mechanisms inside. Having known the tubular locks in Canada that can be opened (unlatched) by turning the knob either way I know I'll be annoyed by the fact our doors won't open that way (depending on which hand I'll be using, etc).

I see no technical reason why mortice locks couldn't work this way, but I don't even really know what to search for. Can anyone help with that - if possible even by giving me some *French* search terms (given that's where I live)?

Replacing the mechanisms with tubular locks would be an option, but they'd have to be drop-in replacements that don't leave gaping holes in the side of the door, and they'll have to accept the knobs my wife already bought (which fit on the usual square metal bar that runs through the lock). Requirements that can be resumed as "the wife shouldn't be able to notice a difference" ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried asking a commercial locksmith? Also, what's driving the choice of knobs over handles?

Comment: I'm not aware of any locksmiths locally, all we have is the kind of supermarket-like stores catering to DIYers and professionals who know what they need. As to the 2nd question; I think the answer is clear from the OP and otherwise irrelevant...